# Combining touching polygons, keeping all attributes from Class "A" feature, using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, merge

How to automatically merge polygons sharing a common boundary, keeping all attributes from class "A" features?

Interactively I would do this in an edit session by:

- selecting all objects of Name "One",
- [Editor toolbar >> Merge](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/creating-new-features/merging-features-in-the-same-layer.htm),
- choose Class "A" to be the parent/master feature.

Repeat for features of Name "Two", "Three", ...

*Dissolve* solution from [How to combine adjacent polygons sharing similar trait into single polygon?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23365/how-to-combine-adjacent-polygons-sharing-similar-trait-into-single-polygon?rq=1) doesn't work because we need to keep other attributes which differ. In other words:

- Dissolve/merge touching polygons where geometry [Name] is identical
- Keep attributes from polygon with [Class] A (if multiple Class A's, ok to just keep first one)
- Discard attributes from other features

[image: Before and after example]

[image: Annotated table, what to keep and discard]

Comment: To do this I would use Polygon Neighbors first to create a table from which to look up which polygons are neighbors and then to run a cursor through the feature class updating variable values as you wish as well as one to flag whether it should be dissolved as a final step.

Comment: If you have networkx module I can post solution that uses it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create two copies of the layer for this feature class.  In one layer I would select everything.  In the other layer I would select just the polygons with a Class of "A".  I would use Spatial Join using the layer with all features selected as the target and the layer with just Class A features as the Join layer.  I would use the keep all target features option and the One to One option.

The output will have duplicate fields, Select all records where the Name and Name_1 fields contain the same values.  This will be the set of all the features that touched a Class A feature and had a matching Name value.  Calculate the Class field of the Target to be "A".  Calculate over the Code_1 and waterDefinition_1 fields into the Code and waterDefinition fields to set these values to match the value of the touching Class A feature.

Now you can Dissolve all of the features and use all of the target fields as Dissolve fields (Not the fields ending in _1) to preserve the unique attribute cases.  Uncheck the Create Multi-part feature option. If a feature was not touched by a Class A feature it will have its original attributes.  Merge of these features would only occur if they were touching features that had the same attribute values that are not Class A attributes.  However, all features that touched a Class A feature will now be merged together and have the Class A attributes.

Comment: +1 However I'd first exported B that don't share a boundary with A first and delete all of the attributes in remaining B. Not sure this will work if there is ABB polygons in 1 'row'

Comment: Exporting the B polygons avoids two B polygons dissolving together when they had the exact same attributes, so that is fine.  No need to void the attributes of the remaining B polygons.  The Spatial Join would have Null in all of the join fields when a Class A polygon does not touch a Class B polygon.  There is a possible worry if two same Case Class A polygons with an attribute difference touch the same Class B polygon, but do not touch each other, since only one of the Class A polygons would dissolve with the Class B polygon.  A second iteration of the process would eliminate that set.

Comment: Spatial Join is key. I had explored and rejected this earlier because of resulting nulls in the attributes I wanted to keep (wrong _Match Option_) . With your encouragement to look at it again I found something that works, and discovered a simplification of your method too! More coming when I get my notes in better shape.

Answer (score 0):

Dissolve does work, just not on it's own. Spatial Join as well, but it too is insufficient on it's own. I had explored and rejected both of these earlier because of of losing wanted attributes altogether (Dissolve) or resulting nulls in the attributes I need to keep (Spatial Join). With @Richard's answer we're reoriented properly. The solution:

1. **Dissolve** on the common field, `Name`. We lose all other attributes but that's ok as it's only the geometry we'll keep from this step.
2. Collect the attributes we want and make them portable with **Make Feature Layer** (or a Definition Query or interactive selection or ...) and **Feature to Points**. Make sure to select INSIDE so the points are always inside the polygons.
3. Transfer the attributes from the points to the empty polygons with **Spatial Join**, use Match Option CLOSEST. One to one and One to Many don't seem to differ for the data I'm working with.

[image: Model diagram]

Expressed in arcpy:

```
# original feature class: border_lakes
# final feature class: dissolved_border_lakes_with_attributes
# all others can be discarded (tip: use "in_memory" workspace)

arcpy.Dissolve_management(in_features="border_lakes", 
    out_feature_class="dissolved_border_lakes", 
    dissolve_field="Name", statistics_fields="", 
    multi_part="MULTI_PART", 
    unsplit_lines="DISSOLVE_LINES")

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features="border_lakes", 
    out_layer="selected_border_lakes", 
    where_clause="Class LIKE 'A'")

arcpy.FeatureToPoint_management(in_features="selected_border_lakes",
    out_feature_class="attribute_points", 
    point_location="INSIDE")

arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(target_features="dissolved_border_lakes", 
    join_features="attribute_points", 
    out_feature_class="dissolved_border_lakes_with_attributes", 
    join_operation="JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", 
    join_type="KEEP_ALL", 
    field_mapping="", 
    match_option="CLOSEST", 
    search_radius="", 
    distance_field_name="")
```

.

---

Spatial Join in step 3 is where I went wrong at first and ended up with null attributes or other unwanted combinations. I was choosing HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN and WITHIN. It was the interactive Spatial Join from the ArcMap table of contents, with it's different wording from the geoprocessing tool, that gave me the final clue.

I suspect it possible to use spatial join without using the point file intermediary, but wasn't successful with our data. Having something that works is good enough for now; I'll leave further optimization for others.

[image: Interactive Spatial Join dialog]